# What twist was originally envisioned for the ST: VOY episode "Innocence"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In [ST:VOY 2x22 "Innocence"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Innocence_(episode)), Tuvok is trapped on a moon with a bunch of children from a nearby world. It turns out the apparent children are actually old people, as the respective species "ages backwards" (whatever this is supposed to mean - it sounds completely nonsensical to me).

In any case, [Memory Alpha's background information section](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Innocence_(episode)#Background_information) seems to imply the original script by Anthony Williams had a *different* resolution to the story. It indicates this several times, but weasels around describing what was different about it:

- "Although the premise for this episode was pitched by Anthony Williams, it was slightly different from how the story turned out and Lisa Klink was not completely in favor of the initial idea." - but in the following, the text only revolves around the premise rather than the resolution.
- "Lisa Klink struggled to come up with a science fiction twist to the story." - this clearly states the twist ending about reverse aging was not in the original script. Thus, either there was a different twist ending (that is somehow not given away on MA, or in the source it cites), or there was none (in which case it is not clear why one had to be added, given that the episode focused on the social aspects of having a Vulcan care for children).
- This is followed by an even more explicit statement: "We didn't end up going with [Anthony Williams'] sci-fi-premise, but the idea that something mysterious was happening to [the kids] kind of stayed with it, and it ended up being the reverse-aging thing." - thus, obviously there *was* a *different* sci-fi twist that explained the kids' disappearance.

**Is it known what the sci-fi twist in Anthony Williams' original script was?**

Comment: If memory serves, the kids were disappearing one-by-one and turning into pure energy. I can't for the life of me remember where I read that.

Comment: @Valorum That actually happened in the episode, I believe.

Comment: @Rainbow - I mean without the growing younger schtick.

Comment: See also for aging backwards Mork and Mindy and ST:TAS The Counter-Clock Incident.  There is a subtle difference between being born old (mork&mindy) and a time reversed universe (TAS) and aging to a certain point before it goes in reverse.  Not sure Voyager left enough ambiguity for this last option.  I'm inclined to think not, it was not that clever.  In real life there's a species of immortal jellyfish that can revert its age and keep going back and forth between old and young endlessly.

Comment: And also see the Buck Rogers in the 25th Century episode "the Golden Man" Feb. 19, 1981.

Comment: @Valorum Okay, but still that means that they didn't switch plots, but merge them, so the different sci-fi twist was the original plot.

Answer (score 2):

From your question:

> "Although the premise for this episode was pitched by Anthony Williams, it was slightly different from how the story turned out and Lisa Klink was not completely in favor of the initial idea." - but in the following, the text only revolves around the premise rather than the resolution.

It's clear from the full quotes (below) that Lisa Klink was unhappy with the sitcom-like character of the initial idea - this has nothing to do with the resolution.

> "Lisa Klink struggled to come up with a science fiction twist to the story." - this clearly states the twist ending about reverse aging was not in the original script.

This is a mistake on Memory Alpha. The original quote states that she struggled to come up with a science fiction *spin* to the story. So this is not about changing one twist to another, but making this story fit into a sci fi show.

> This is followed by an even more explicit statement: "We didn't end up going with [Anthony Williams'] sci-fi-premise, but the idea that something mysterious was happening to [the kids] kind of stayed with it, and it ended up being the reverse-aging thing." - thus, obviously there was a different sci-fi twist that explained the kids' disappearance.

When authors pitched their ideas back then, they usually did not include a full script, but simply pitched the ideas. The way I read the full quotes, it seems to me that Klink was unhappy with the overall premise and changed it, retaining the disappearing kids-theme and making it darker.

Here is the full quote from ["Captains Log: Supplemental"](https://archive.org/details/captainslogssupp0000gros/page/166/mode/2up?q=innocence), which was quoted in the Memory Alpha article:

[image: Captains Log: Supplemental Quote]

> **"I was not all that excited with the premise," says Lisa Klink. "It sounded like a sitcom episode.** But what ultimately caught my attention was the idea of Tuvok as a father. What are Vulcan fathers like? Are their kids born logical? Probably not."
> **Klink's problem, however, was finding a science-fiction spin for the traditional storytelling motif.** "The rest of the staff came to my rescue there," says Klink, "because I had nothing to do with that concept. The freelancer Anthony Williams had pitched us an idea where these kids were in trouble and they were disappearing one by one into this cave. We didn't end up going with his sci-fi premise, but the idea that something mysterious was happening to them kind of stayed with it, and it ended up being the reverse aging thing. Actually, once the whole death thing came up, it helped a lot, because it took the cutesy edge off it. It added a layer of darkness over the whole thing. We even started off the episode with a crewman dying."

*(Captains' Logs Supplemental: The Unauthorized Guide to the New Trek Voyages)*

And here is the full quote from [Cinefantastique](https://archive.org/details/cinefantastique_1970-2002/Cinefantastique%20Vol%2028%20No%204-5%20%28Nov%201996%29/page/n103/mode/2up?q=Klink):

[image: Cinefantastique]

> "I was really, really pleased with it," said Lisa Klink. "The premise sounds hokey - Tuvok is trapped on a planet with a bunch of children - but it really isn't as hokey as it sounds. **When they gave me that premise to work on, my reaction was, 'God, this is going to be a sit-com.'** It really did not turn out that way at all. I think it all came together well [...].

*(Cinefantastique, Vol. 28, No. 4/5)*

Comment: I'm going to have to go with the OP's interpretation of the article.  It sounds as if the original pitch is "Tuvok on a moon with disappearing children", that pitch may have included the children getting to a certain age and turning into energy such as the show, all while Tuvok grapples with dealing with the kids and them disappearing.  That would be sitcom-ie.  They kept the main concept of Tuvok being a dad and the kids disappearing and spun it so they were aging backwards and their minds had invented a monster story with the cave.